# Perplexing series!

Tags: sequences-and-series

The value of 
$$(x+y)(x-y)+\frac{1}{2!}(x+y)(x-y)(x^2+y^2)+\frac{1}{3!}(x+y)(x-y)(x^4+y^4+x^2y^2)+\ldots$$
is
$$(A)\quad e^{x^2}+e^{y^2}\quad\quad(B)\quad e^{x^2-y^2}\quad\quad(C)\quad e^{x^2}-e^{y^2}\quad\quad(D)\quad \text{ none of these}$$

I got this when I was learning advance series. I tried Arithmetic-Geometric progression and I think it's getting messed up. I was also thinking if there's a clever approach to this.

Thanks!

Comment: $+ \infty$?  Oh, my god...

Comment: You will need to know the series for the function $e^x$.  Non-mathematicians sometimes write $+\infty$ on the end of a series to mean "it's an infinite series".

Comment: I think it's just an infinite series.

Comment: The statement of the problem is rather laughable, because the pattern of the terms is recognizable if and only if you already know the answer. Otherwise, coming up with an actual formula for $a_n$ in $\sum_n a_n$ is a challenge in itself.

Comment: I figured that's what it meant and I stand by my original statement.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but it's a grade 12 problem! I'm still working on it! Please get your hands dirty with this problem too. Thanks!

Comment: Try simplifying the first $3$ terms(what is $(x-y)(x+y)$?,what is $(x+y)(x-y)(x^2+y^2)$?, what is $(x+y)(x-y)(x^4+y^4+x^2y^2)$?) and try to compare them with the $3$ solutions

Comment: None of these because the sum is $$e^{x^2}-e^{y^2}-1$$
The sum should be  $1+(x^2-y^2)+(x^4-y^4)/2!+\ldots$ to give answer (C)

Comment: @Raffaele Can you post the solution as I'm not sure how'd you get this!(been solving it for 3 days).

Comment: $(x-y)(x+y) = x^2 - y^2$  the trick here is recoginising that each term simplifies to $x^{2n}-y^{2n}$  Then you can break this into a power series for $x$ and a series $y.$

Comment: @Raffaele  $(1+ x^2 + \frac {x^4}{2!} \cdots) - (1+ y^2 + \frac {y^4}{2!} \cdots) =  x^2- y^2 + \frac {x^4-y^4}{2!} \cdots$

Comment: @DougM Yes yes, I saw my mistake. Thank you

Comment: At the very least, A and B can be ruled out by plugging in $x=y$ to both choices and the given expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{{n=0}}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}-y^{2n}}{n!}=\sum_{{n=0}}^{\infty}\frac{(x^2)^n-(y^2)^n}{n!}=e^{x^2}-e^{y^2}$$

More explanation
$(x+y)(x-y)=x^2-y^2$

$(x+y)(x-y)(x^2+y^2)=x^4-y^4$

$(x+y)(x-y)(x^4+x^2y^2+y^4)=(x^2+y^2)(x^4+x^2y^2+y^4)=x^6-y^6$

So we can expect that the general term is $(x^2)^n-(y^2)^n$

Recall that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x$$
Thus $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x^2)^n}{n!}=e^{x^2}$$

PS

The $n=0$ issue is not a problem because for $n=0$ the term is $x^0-y^0=0$ therefore I was wrong in my comment before. The correct answer is (C)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea!